# Not Able to Create The Master Detail Relationship Field on Invoice Object

Tags: lookup, account, master-detail

[image]

I am facing this error.... My goal is to create the relationship between Account and Invoice Object..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using standard Invoice object, you can't create master detail relationship here.

As per documentation

> You can define master-detail relationships between custom objects or
> between a custom object and a standard object. However, the standard
> object cannot be on the detail side of a relationship with a custom
> object.

You can't add M-D relationship between Standard-Standard object.
Reason for not allowing this could be some internal engine as M-D impacts security and sharing